# cannot unmarshal array into Go struct when decoding array

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to properly decode JSON String to an object.

I defined the following structs:

```
type AjaxModelsList struct {
    Id float64 `json:"Id"`
    Name string `json:"Name"`
    CarId float64 `json:"CarId"`
    EngName string `json:"EngName"`
}

type AjaxModelsData struct {
    ModelList []AjaxModelsList `json:"ModelList"`
}

type AjaxModels struct {
    Status bool `json:"status"`
    Data map[string]AjaxModelsData `json:"data"`

}
```

the defined object is

```
{
 "status": true,
 "data": {
 "ModelList": [{
   "Id": 1,
   "Name": "foo",
   "CarId": 1,
   "EngName": "bar"
  }]
 }
}
```

and I unmarshall using the following code:

```
c :=AjaxModels{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(body_byte,&c); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("an error occured: %v",err)
}
```

and I get the following output:

```
an error occured: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field AjaxModels.data of type main.AjaxModelsData
```

since I used `[]AjaxModelsList` it's a slice so I shouldn't be getting this error. I probably missed something, but what ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170462/discussion-between-ufk-and-flimzy).

Comment: @Flimzy apparently the error message is using the tag or json key: https://play.golang.org/p/FhS6ekOdxiS

Comment: @mkopriva: Fascinating. And misleading. But good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `json` the `data` structure is `object[key]array`, while in Go `Data` is `map[key]struct.slice`. Change `Data` to be `map[key]slice` instead.

E.g.

```
type AjaxModels struct {
    Status bool                      `json:"status"`
    Data   map[string][]AjaxModelsList `json:"data"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Sh_vKVL-D--